# Spring create bean from class in jar

Tags: java, spring, jar, javabeans

I have two maven projects. One is dependecy and generate jar file. When I include it to other webapp maven project, eclipse recognize it but when i start server (tomcat) I get error that class cannot be found.

In project where generate jar I have simple interafce (SimpleService.java) and interfaceImplementation (SimpleServiceImpl.java). In webapp maven project I have services.xml

```
    <bean id="simpleDao" class="com.example.SimpleDao">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="simpleService" class="com.example.SimpleServiceImpl">
        <property name="simpleDao" ref="simpleDao"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter">      
        <property name="serviceName" value="simpleService"/>       
        <property name="service" ref="simpleService"/>   
        <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.example.SimpleService"/>
        <property name="registryPort" value="1099"/>
    </bean>
```

I get error that class `com.example.SimpleDao` is not found (it is in jar not in project). I am sure that I have included jar file. It is also located in .war under ../WEB-INF/lib if I start maven install.

Comment: If the error is a ClassNotFoundException, check if the jar inside the  ../WEB-INF/lib folder has the SimpleDao.class file. This shouldn't be related to Spring, but with Maven build.

Comment: what is scope of your dependent jars in webapp project's pom.xml?

Comment: please post your pom.xml file

Comment: in targer/appName/WEB-INF/lib/com/example is SimpleDao.class; I have not specifed any extra scope of depency. Which pom.xml do you need. pom.xml od dependcy project or webapp project ..in dependcy project i set packing jar and in webapp project i just add depency as normal artifactId, groupId and version